# Batch is starting too fast after reboot

Tags: windows, boot, batch-file

So i have batch1 as this

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /V 2 /D "%~d0\bat\batch2.bat /f
```

and then I reboot the computer (Windows 8) and batch2 starts.

It seems like the batch file is starting before windows because there is only a black background and the cmd window.

When I "x" the batchfile, windows continues booting.

My problem is that I need the computer connectet to internet to get my batch working.

So I need the batch to load after windows has finished loading.

Any clue? :-)

Comment: Try `start /?` in command line. It's not a program but a built-in command, so you may have to run it via `cmd`'s argument.

Comment: Im not sure if i understand you. Should i set start /? in my batch2? issnt start /? just list off start commands?

Comment: `start /?` displays help for the `start` command. Run it in a command line, read what it says and decide if it's what you need. (it probably is)

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not give it into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Keys under HKLM are running after system load, HKCU keys are running after user logon.
2. For delay the execution (if you need internet connection), give at the first position

   ```
   ping -n 10 127.0.0.1>nul
   ```

   for 10 second delay.

Comment: Wet kiss in tha face! Big tanks! I will test it out!

Comment: Or you could just do `sleep 10` for 10 seconds delay ;)

Comment: Yes, you could also use sleep, but using ping on loopback is faster (for CPU), than using sleep.exe